# MySQL: group by `topic_id`, if `topic_id` > 0

Tags: mysql

I have `entries` which might or might not be assigned to a `topic`.

I want to select entries with the highest score by summing up the score of those, which belong to the same topic. In addition, I want to get a number of similar entries, which were grouped together.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`topic_id`) FROM `entries`
GROUP BY `topic_id` HAVING `topic_id` > 0
ORDER BY SUM(`score`) DESC LIMIT 30
```

This query misses a few things. Firstly, I want entries without topic_id (topic_id = 0) not to be grouped, but to be treated individually. Secondly, COUNT(`topic_id`) does not always return a real number of entries belonging to the same topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(    
    SELECT topic_id,COUNT(*),SUM(`score`) AS sum
    FROM `entries`
    WHERE `topic_id` > 0
    GROUP BY `topic_id`
UNION
    SELECT topic_id, 1,1 AS sum
    FROM `entries`
    WHERE `topic_id` = 0
)
ORDER BY sum DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: But this doesn't include individual entries without topic_id, does it?

Comment: edited my query according to your comment, if you mean entries without topic_id = entries with topic_id=0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `topic_id` > 0 IsGroupedTopid,
    if(`topic_id`>0, `topic_id`, id) TopicOrEntryId,
    COUNT(*) CountEntries,
    SUM(`score`) TotalScore
FROM `entries`
GROUP BY
    `topic_id` > 0,
    if(`topic_id`>0, `topic_id`, id)
ORDER BY SUM(`score`) DESC
LIMIT 30;
```